# Convert words to hyperlinks

Tags: javascript

I want to turn certain words within the tables on a page into links.

As an example, I'd like to turn every occurrence of the word "hello" in the text  into `<a href="http://example.com/hello">hello</a>`.

The words in question are stored in an array. The page contains multiple tables.

This seem more difficult than I thought. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a bit unclear without a sample of your arrays.

Comment: Sorry. The array is just a regular array of strings (words) like "hello", "ABBA", "sal governale's pouch".